# When is .ss domain going to be available?

Tags: discussion

So, I opened a question yesterday -> [When is .ss domain going to be available?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95858/when-is-ss-domain-going-to-be-available)

John says that this is offtopic question for ProWebmasters, so I'm putting this on meta, so we can do a discussion about this, because this is a interesting situation.

**.ss** is the designated country code top-level domain (ccTLD) for South Sudan in the Domain Name System of the Internet. It is derived from the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code for South Sudan, which is SS.

According to CIO East Africa, the TLD was allocated on 10 August 2011 following the country's declaration of independence from Sudan. The TLD was registered on 31 August 2011; as of 8 December 2015, it is not in the DNS root zone and thus not operational.

Before .ss was successfully registered, the country's Undersecretary for Telecommunications had initially been concerned about the ccTLD request's possible rejection due to SS also being an abbreviation for Schutzstaffel, the paramilitary force of Nazi Germany.

Before the independence of South Sudan, the applicable domain was .sd, Sudan's top-level Internet domain.

So my question is this:

When is .ss domain going to be available for all mortals, and how to stop domain names to be (for example) **jewish-community.ss** or similar unappropriate or maybe insulting names?

Also, how is it even possible that no one didn't stop this?

Comment: It sounds like "when is it going to be available" is pure speculation and "how is it possible" is asking for opinions.

Comment: I didn't put this here so it can be a speculation, I putted this here so we can discuss this theme because it's too broad for main site. They gave them that domain. I don't know which level of infrastructure is there and what needs to be done to get it available.

Comment: I thought you put this here to discuss the reasons the question was closed.   Meta is for discussing issues that effect the main site, not as a place to post questions that are off-topic there.

Comment: Well, s#$t. :) I thought that we can have a discussion about this here. Shame. :)

Comment: We do however have our [super duper chat channel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters) for off-topic questions and extended discussion.

Comment: @JosipIvic I had commented in our chat room regarding why your question was considered off-topic and that it would be better to ask here on Meta rather than in our chat room. If you still want to discuss why your question put on hold, you can edit this Meta question to discuss why it was considered off-topic, with just the link back to your original question on the main site.

Comment: I know this question is off-topic and that you have now been disappointed twice, however, I do like the question. For what it is worth! Cheers!!